# jQuery: both .ready() and .ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery

I want some part of my JS to initialize when document is ready OR when ajax query completed
Something like this:

```
if ($(document).ready() or $(document).ajaxComplete()) {
  // do something
}
```

Is it possible to write such a a condition?
And how do I make it right?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense though. Those are two completely independent events. You usually put stuff in the `ready` handler which has to access the DOM. The Ajax callback OTOH could be executed before the DOM is ready and the elements are available. Please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: you are doing ajax request before jquery is loaded ? you are loading jquery before the html ? if not no no then i advise you go for no no instead & then your question becomes irrelevant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

u can use bind Function

```
 $(document).bind('ready ajaxComplete', function(){
  // Your code here
 })
```

Though I agree with Felix in comments that ready function is a separate function mostly used to carry actions only when entire document is loaded

Comment: `.ready` and `.ajaxComplete` are special functions. I don't think you can substitute them with `.bind`.

Comment: To be tested : but jQuery's doc mentions "jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event"

Comment: am bit confused & unsure of my own answer now.. Is ready &  ajaxComplete considered as events like click, change ?

Comment: Judging from this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m6E8y/1/ , it works (both events are fired, with all jQuery versions available in jsfiddle). For the `ready` event, however, the doc says "deprecated in 1.8" (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Seems not working when called from deferred external script

Answer (score 4):

You can put your common code in a function, and bind it to as many events as you want :

```
function doStuff(){
    // do something
}

$(document).ready(doStuff);
$(document).ajaxComplete(doStuff);
```

As Jigar mentionned : you can also use `.bind('evtA evtB', func)` or `.on('evtA evtB', func)` to bind the same callback to several events in one go.

However, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for the `ready` callback says :

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: In that case he would have to set a flag whether the code has already been executed to prevent it from running twice.

Comment: Your answer seems better..less controversial than mine :p yes, a flag would be required as mentioned by @Derija93