# Jquery being loaded after AJAX in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function PostLinkHome() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.post-link-home').find('.elementor-post').each(function() {
            let link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            $(this).wrapAll(document.createElement('a'));
            $(this).closest('a').attr('href', link);
        });
        jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            PostLinkHome();
        });
    });
});
```

Which is suppose to run the Jquery function `PostLinkHome()` before and after Ajax has been loaded.

I have tried to do this:

```
jQuery(document).bind('ready ajaxComplete', function($) {
    $('.post-link-home').find('.elementor-post').each(function() {
        let link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $(this).wrapAll(document.createElement('a'));
        $(this).closest('a').attr('href', link);
    });
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267072/jquery-both-ready-and-ajaxcomplete/19267134)

But this didn't work.

The problem is that the code works but once the Ajax is loaded, it loads the jQuery again, to the previous items in the loop which already had the function applied to them before the Ajax loading more things.

This results in the Ajax items having the jQuery applied to them but the old items on the page get the same script applied to them twice which is a problem.

Comment: Why are you mixing `DOMContentLoaded` and jQuery's document ready?

Comment: Your code really makes little sense. You are calling the function and then you are assigning the function. Why is `jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            PostLinkHome();
        });` inside the function `PostLinkHome`?

Comment: @epascarello I am not so versed in coding but I got the code from here: https://elementorforum.com/threads/how-can-i-put-a-link-to-the-whole-box-instead-of-just-the-title-and-the-image-blog-post-element.6193/ . I did see it in other places as well.

Comment: @epascarello It's because there is an ajax function which this jquery needs to work on (infinite scroll) so I need the jquery to be executed on the ajax loaded items also. Here is the source for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315294/run-js-code-on-load-and-on-ajax-loaded-content although I see the comments there saying what you're saying if I understood correctly.

Comment: Note that `.wrapAll(document.createElement(‘a’))` could be written more concisely as `.wrapAll(“<a></a>”)`, but it seems a little odd to wrap a link in a link (not to mention being invalid HTML).

Answer (score 2):

Just define the code you want to run in a function. Call it on document ready and bind it to the Ajax call. (Side note: seems odd you would run this code on every Ajax call and not just the one you make that returns the content)

```
function PostLinkHome() {
  $('.post-link-home .elementor-post').each(function() {
    const elem = $(this);

    // if parent is already a link, just exit out
    if(elem.parent().is('a')) return;


    const link = elem.find('a').attr('href');
    elem.wrapAll(document.createElement('a'));
    elem.closest('a').attr('href', link);
  });
}

// Then bind the event and call the function

jQuery(function () {
  jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(PostLinkHome);
  PostLinkHome();
});
```

Seems odd because this code would put a link in a link? My guess you would want to unwrap the initial link.

```
const linkElem = elem.find('a');
const link = linkElem.attr('href');
linkElem.children().unwrap();
```

Comment: The code is meant to add a link to a whole section (to the wrapper). It works well. I am just not sure how to implement it after ajax loaded more posts (it works on them also), the issue is that it then adds the same wrapper link to everything before, every time more posts load with ajax.

Comment: So check to see if the link exists (and yes you have a problem with a link in a link)

Comment: the link exists but that's the issue. How do I make it only run on the newly loaded posts, and not every time ajax is complete.